how to assign Ao image in blender?
Are there any simple ways to apply an ambient occlusion (AO) texture on top of a base color texture without using mix or math nodes?

OK, I am extremely curious - WHY? Why wouldn't you use color mix node?

As @MartynasŽiemys says in his answer, no there is no way of applying an AO texture (or any texture) to another texture without using the nodes which are used to apply textures to each other. The only other way: pre-mix them in an image editing software like Photoshop, but of course then you lose all flexibility of changing the mixing in Blender.

thanks that was useful. i am trying to upload a model to turbosquid market to certify steam cell it need to satisfy some criteria such as no procedural nodes and ao is compulsory is there any way to do it

So are you talking about the Ambient Occlusion shader node which is found in the Input category? That's not a texture, which might explain why we are a bit confused... I guess you would have to bake the output of the Ambient Occlusion to a regular image so that you can use it like other textures.


Are there any simple ways to apply an ambient occlusion (AO) texture
on top of a base color texture without using mix or math nodes?

No. There are really no ways to do that without using nodes that are used to do that. You need to multiply one by another and without mix or math nodes you just cannot do that.

How to assign AO image in Blender?

Ambient occlusion is mostly an artistic effect in Cycles. Cycles calculates somewhat realistic lighting and shadows so any ambient light is occluded by your scene anyway, so you use AO textures any way you want really. It's is probably most usual to multiply the diffuse color by it. One would normally use a Mix Color node in Multiply mode to do this and if needed additional nodes like for example Map Range could be used for finer control. This is just one of the most widely used ways, but it is certainly not a rule. You can use AO for various things in any way you want. AO is often used with various techniques to generate things like dirt masks for example.
